# RINEX specs and OS library

Tags: gps, rinex

Is there any OS library to read/write/process [RINEX data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RINEX)?

I've been wanting to start a OS library to read and write RINEX, which is something I need for a project, but not actually post-process them.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GPSTk](http://www.gpstk.org/bin/view/Documentation/WebHome) has a suite of utilities to "examine, manipulate, and plot RINEX observation files".